# C# - Selenium - OPenQA.Selenium.Firefox

Tags: c#, selenium

The system cannot find the file specified

Code as below-

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");
```

Comment: Enter url as `https://www.google.com`

Answer (score 0):

You can use-

1. `driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");`
2. `driver.get(URL);`